# Using iFrames to embed flowplayer 5.4

Tags: php, html, iframe, video, flowplayer

I'm using the following code to embed flowplayer on one of my sites.

`<IFRAME SRC="http://mydomain.com/video/9" FRAMEBORDER=0 MARGINWIDTH=0 MARGINHEIGHT=0 SCROLLING=NO WIDTH=640 HEIGHT=360></IFRAME>`

The link `mydomain.com/video/9` has the flowplayer video with 100% width / height. Using an iframe on another will have work initially, but if I refresh this error comes up: `html5: Video file not found` so then I go back to the initial link `mydomain.com/video/9`, also displays the same error `html5: Video file not found`. But If I go to the original location of the video, the video still exists!

Then I remove the iframe from the other site, and the video magically starts displaying on `mydomain.com/video/9`. Why is that, and how can I make it so it allows iFrames?

Comment: Why iframe anyway? Its suck a dumb hack. If the site is yours just embed it.

Comment: iFrames are easy and their isn't any hassle, plus I want to protect my video file's location.

Comment: Trust me, you are not protecting it.

Comment: In any case, I want to utilize their id's to get the embed code, and iframes can do that.

Comment: Anyway if you expect some help you will have to provide some more code than just your iframe tag.